# Show Joomla 3.2 Article Without Home In URL

Tags: url, seo, url-rewriting, joomla3.2

Installed Joomla 3.2 on local dev machine and renamed htaccess

Configuration:
Search Engine Friendly URLs: Yes
Use URL rewriting: Yes

It will be used for blogging so looking for clean URLs with home page set to showcase different items and not just blog articles.

Each article I create looks like this:
http://www.example.com/**home**/wordpress-or-joomla

What can I do to remove "home" from the URL so it is not included when shared?

Answer (score 0):

Only one, easy-to-do method:
You need to make first level menu items for each blog article you create. (in another menu, hidden, not published in any module)
Pluses: you can full customize parameters for this article: alias, seo params, etc.
Minuses: double work: create article + create menu item.
Little manual:

1. **Menus** -> **Menu Manager** -> **Add New Menu**
2. Type title (ex.: Blog Menu) and Menu type (ex.: blogmenu) **Save**
3. Go to **Menus** -> **Blog Menu** (for ex.)
4. Click **New**
5. Menu item type: **Articles** -> **Single Article**
6. Select Article (select any article you like)
7. Menu title (field above) : you can just manual type the same title that Article have
8. Alias: type alias you like (ex.: puppies-for-all) Alias is part of Search Engine Friendly URL
9. Click **Save&Close**
10. Go to frontend, refresh page where your blog is- hover on article title (the one that you make menu item for) and you'll see new neat URL.
11. Do the same for other blog items

Comment: Can you add additional steps to show how this is done? I went into **Menus** > **Main Menu** > **Add New Menu Item** and then see so many other options.